# How do I point Docker's device value towards the Ubuntu WSL file system on my Windows 11 Home machine?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Earlier today my senior dev noticed Docker was getting ~1% of CPU resources on my computer. Thus started a quest to discover the source of the issue and a solution to give Docker more resources. Restart times were 8 min on my machine and 10 sec on his. The goal is to reduce restart time down to < 30 seconds.

He linked me [this article from the Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/why-is-my-php-docker-container-so-slow-on-windows-11/119242/2) by someone with a similar problem. The OP says he "created a docker volume that points to the WSL filesystem" to implement a solution, and used this command for Docker:

```
docker volume create --driver local -o o=bind -o type=none -o device="\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\user\sulu" php
```

I am on Windows 11 Home and have just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.04. I copied Ubuntu just incidentally; I heard it's good. Anyway, I am now stuck wondering, what is wrong with this command I tried?

```
docker volume create --driver local -o o=bind -o type=none -o device="\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04"
```

There is nothing in my /home folder in Ubuntu, so I won't be copying the `\home\user\sulu` part.

The above command yields: `Error response from daemon: can't access specified distro mount service: stat /run/guest-services/distro-services/ubuntu-20.04.sock: no such file or directory`

I am a Docker newbie and really don't know what I'm doing. I just want to build my container! Thanks